# Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;I)V]

Tags: java, ehcache

I am getting this exception:

> Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> net.sf.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;I)V]

We are using the following dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.ehcache-spring-annotations</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache-spring-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: This most likely means that you are using incompatible versions of ehcache and ehcache-spring-annotations. Look in the documentation of those libraries which versions are compatible with each other and use the right versions.